# Working with timezones and daylight savings time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc, dst

My single-page javascript app retrieves data in JSON format via REST calls. Dates come formatted using the UTC timezone in standard ISO8601 format, such as `2011-02-04T19:31:09Z`.

When signing up for the service, users select their timezone from a drop down list. This timezone could be different than the user's browser's timezone. The javascript app knows what the user's selected timezone is at all times.

I know how to convert the UTC string into a date. I understand that Javascript only represents dates in the local timezone.

But I'm having troubles figuring out **how to display a date formatted for a timezone OTHER than the user's local timezone**. It must account for DST on all dates. Internally, I want to deal with all dates as UTC and only convert to string representation of a date in another timezone at display time. I need to display the dates in the timezone selected in the user's profile, not their browser's timezone.

I've experimented with the server sending the timezone offset difference in milliseconds between the user's browser's timezone and the user's profile timezone. But I've found I can't just send one offset value, but need to send an offset for every date to account for variations in DST.

Any suggestions or sample code on how to display dates formatted in various timezones? The options I've found so far:

1. Server sends dates as strings already formatted in the right timezone and no date parsing or manipulation is done on the client. This makes doing certain things on the client difficult if not impossible.
2. Use a library such as https://github.com/mde/timezone-js, which includes the entire Olson TZ database into Javascript. This means longer load times more memory usage, etc.
3. Send a timezoneOffsetMillis value with every date sent to the client. This results in messy JSON data and non-optimal REST interfaces.

Are there any simpler or better solutions?

Comment: It may not work in your app but on the web it's often easier to display the age of something instead of trying to reliably display a date and time in the user timezone. For instance "asked 6min ago" on SO.

Comment: @Alexandre -- Thanks, and I already do that where possible, such as last login dates, post dates, etc. But my app needs to display specific dates and times for events that take place in various timezones. I can't use relative times or ages for this.

Comment: I would definitely go for timezone-js, it would be the "correct" way to do it. You can also couple it with the following timezone detection script: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/.

Comment: @Jon, I agree it is the correct way to go, but it sure will add some bloat. I wish JS had supported timezones from the start. Thanks for the pointer to jstimezonedetect. I've seen its demo page before but forgot about it.

Comment: In that case I would offload the tz work using the zoneinfo files to the server and have it return local datetime through json, formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 is a bad idea since, as you pointed out, it increases load times. If I were you I would do a combination of 1 and 3. I don't agree that this makes the JSON data messy or the REST interface non-optimal.

This is a classic tradeoff where to accept a bit more complexity in the protocol in order to simplify the client-side code.

Comment: Thanks, but I have an idea to keep the JSON clean. What if I sent all dates that should be shown in the user's local timezones in UTC format like `2011-02-03T09:31:35Z`. Any dates that should be shown in a specific timezone would be sent with that timezone's format like `2011-02-03T14:00:00-0800`. When I originally parse the date, I could retain the offset within a custom property of the date object. I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: @Tauren: With that approach, watch out for automatic time zone conversions if you're doing any date mathematics (adding or removing time) on the client.  For example, if you add 24 hours to a date and cross a daylight savings shift, the time will appear to be off by an hour when converted to a string.  Also, when we shift our clocks backwards, that hour of time is ambiguous in JavaScript.  And when we shift our clocks forward, the hour skipped is not representable (all assuming the local time observes daylight savings), even though that may be the time in your user's chosen time zone.

Answer (score 4):

Fast-forward to 2015, when it comes to **formatting a date from other timezone, using specific locale**, there are two options.

*In the example, I use French locale and will use a (UTC+5) date of 27 March 2016, 2h15  **which is not observed in western Europe (because of DST change**, clock moves from 2h00 to 3h00) which is a common source of bugs.*

### For maximum portability, use [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) library. Moment comes in with bundled [80+ locales](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale).

1. Using timestamp and UTC offset:

   ```
   moment(1459026900000).utcOffset(300).locale('fr').format("LLLL")
   // "dimanche 27 mars 2016 02:15"
   ```
2. Using array of integers (note that in moment, month is 0-based, just like in native JS Date object)

   ```
   moment.utc([2016,3-1,27,2,15]).locale('fr').format("LLLL")
   // "dimanche 27 mars 2016 02:15"
   ```

*You can test those methods by running code in browser's dev tools on http://momentjs.com/*

The tricky part here is to use `moment.utc` which creates a moment date object with UTC flag, meaning that when that date is formatted, it will not be converted to user's timezone, but just displayed as-is (and since UTC does not observe DST, it is not prone to DST bug).

### Future native solution: using `Intl` object

*(note as of late 2015, this solution is supported by Chrome, Firefox, IE11 but still **not supported in Safari 9**)*

Using array of integers:

```
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', { timeZone: 'UTC', weekday: 'long',
          month: 'long', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric',
          minute: 'numeric' })
      .format(Date.UTC(2016,3-1,27,2,15))
    // "dimanche 27 mars 2016 02:15"
```

The key here is once again to use `Date.UTC` and `timeZone: 'UTC'` to make sure the provided date will not be converted to user's local timezone.

---

Note that in both cases we are using UTC methods, just to make sure the date will be used as-is without conversions. It's important though to realize those dates are *fake UTC dates* (they are representing time in a given arbitrary timezone, not UTC time), and should be only used for date formatting and displaying - should not be passed around.

Comment: 2019 note: check also https://date-fns.org/ which is significantly smaller than moment.js and perhaps more suitable from bundle size point of view

Answer (score 0):

have same problem. #1 is solution i guess. You should send all components of date (year, month, day, hours) at special container from client to server