# Date format in Dart which includes GMT

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

How do I convert my current time into GMT/ UTC time in Dart, similar to the javascript way: `new Date().toUTCString()`:

> Tue, 01 Nov 2011 19:06:35 GMT

I tried couple of formatters see below but it did not work

```
//var f = DateFormat('E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
var f = DateFormat('E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'); 
    var date = f.format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: But what about a different user from another timezone, do you want it to also say GMT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Convert your current time to UTC and append `" GMT"` to the string.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var f = DateFormat('E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  var date = f.format(DateTime.now().toUtc()) + " GMT";
  print(date);
}
```

---

### Using an arbitrary timezone (not just GMT/ UTC)

Although it is in the documentation, you can't create strings with arbitrary timezones with DateTime, as timezone support/ implementation has been missing, and is a GitHub issue since 2015. For example, you can't display a different timezone in the string, as using `z` in the format string doesn't work: callers get an `UnimplementedError`. See the 3 related GitHub issues: [one](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/229), [two](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/74) and [three](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/19).

```
UnimplementedError
#0      _DateFormatPatternField.formatTimeZone (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:640:5)
#1      _DateFormatPatternField.formatField (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:381:16)
#2      _DateFormatPatternField.format (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:244:12)
#3      DateFormat.format (package:intl/src/intl/date_format.dart:276:26)
#4      main (file:///Users/benbutterworth/datetime/bin/datetime.dart:11:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Comment: var f = DateFormat('E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z') throws UnimplementedError.

Comment: That's because it's not yet implemented, see my edited answer 

Comment: I am converting javascript equivalent statement new Date().toUTCString() in to equivalent dart. I know there is utc method in dart but that does not produce this output.

Comment: Okay, so in this case, you can just append "GMT" after converting the current time to UTC/ GMT time. This is not a problem of "GMT", but a date conversion, which you can do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26258061/7365866) and maybe [TimeZone package](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) as well.

Comment: I think next time, if you phrase your question with a little more information, I'd be able to help more quickly. I was interested in running dart without Flutter today though, so I am happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
var f = DateFormat('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'); 
var date = f.format(DateTime.now());
```

This output date in format Tue, 01 Nov 2011 19:06:35, without GMT

Comment: That was my question..Its not printing GMT

Comment: Then add it lol, as a string? Or are you saying you want the specific time zone it is called in?

Comment: @BenButterworth I want the current time to display as "Tue, 01 Nov 2011 19:06:35 GMT"

Comment: @AnuranjanSrivastav GMT is set of timezones you want to print in which timezone was this time?

Comment: @savke I am converting javascript equivalent statement new Date().toUTCString() in to equivalent dart. I know there is utc method in dart but that does not produce this output.

Comment: @AnuranjanSrivastav When you convert local date to UTC in flutter you don't get this string GMT, I think that is only difference. You just want GMT on the end if that is than just add it like string.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the work around as below

```
 String getUTCDate() {
    try {
      var f = DateFormat('E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
      var now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
      return f.format(now) + ' GMT';
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error ******' + e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your solution generally works, but it outputs single-digit days when JavaScript's new Date().toUTCString() always outputs double-digit days. Also, you can integrate the "GMT" literal string into the date format. Here is the code I'm using:

`var f = DateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
var now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
return f.format(now);`

Comment: Your original question said `I want to produce an output of date which includes the timezone of the caller`. Calling `.toUTC` includes the timezone of UTC/ GMT, not the timezone of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing use this:

```
final rfc7231DateFormat = "E, d MMM y H:m:s 'GMT'";
final myDate = DateFormat(rfc7231DateFormat).parseUTC(rawValue);
```