# Want to add event in google calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-calendar-api

I want to insert event in google calendar without using any third parties. Please help me if any one know it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You to have the power of Google: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 1):

You want  add some event in google calendar, well you can do this using by following google api library:I posted event to google calendar using below library.

```
https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest
```

They give brief description for adding event to google calendar with code.
    #pragma mark Add, Edit, and Delete an Event

```
- (void)addAnEvent {
  // Make a new event, and show it to the user to edit
  GTLRCalendar_Event *newEvent = [GTLRCalendar_Event object];
 newEvent.summary = @"Sample Added Event";
 newEvent.descriptionProperty = @"Description of sample added event";

 // We'll set the start time to now, and the end time to an hour from 
now,
  // with a reminder 10 minutes before
 NSDate *anHourFromNow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(60 * 60)];

 // Include an offset minutes that tells Google Calendar that these 
dates
  // are for the local time zone.
  NSInteger offsetMinutes = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone].secondsFromGMT / 60;

  GTLRDateTime *startDateTime = [GTLRDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date]offsetMinutes:offsetMinutes];
GTLRDateTime *endDateTime = [GTLRDateTime dateTimeWithDate:anHourFromNow
                                       offsetMinutes:offsetMinutes];

newEvent.start = [GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime object];
newEvent.start.dateTime = startDateTime;

 newEvent.end = [GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime object];
 newEvent.end.dateTime = endDateTime;

  GTLRCalendar_EventReminder *reminder = [GTLRCalendar_EventReminder 
   object];
 reminder.minutes = @10;
reminder.method = @"email";

 newEvent.reminders = [GTLRCalendar_Event_Reminders object];
 newEvent.reminders.overrides = @[ reminder ];
 newEvent.reminders.useDefault = @NO;
  [self addEvent:event];}

- (void)addEvent:(GTLRCalendar_Event *)event {
 GTLRCalendarService *service = self.calendarService;
GTLRCalendar_CalendarListEntry *selectedCalendar = [self 
selectedCalendarListEntry];
 NSString *calendarID = selectedCalendar.identifier;

  GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert *query =
     [GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert queryWithObject:event
                                       calendarId:calendarID];
  self.editEventTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                         completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket 
   *callbackTicket,
     GTLRCalendar_Event *event,
                                        NSError *callbackError) {
 // Callback
 self.editEventTicket = nil;
 if (callbackError == nil) {
   [self displayAlert:@"Event Added"
               format:@"Added event \"%@\"",
    event.summary];
   [self fetchSelectedCalendar];
    } else {
    [self displayAlert:@"Add failed"
               format:@"Event add failed: %@", callbackError];
     } }];

 }

- (void)editSelectedEvent {
 // Show the selected event to the user to edit
 GTLRCalendar_Event *eventToEdit = [self selectedEvent];
 if (eventToEdit) {
  EditEventWindowController *controller = [[EditEventWindowController 
alloc] init];
  [controller runModalForWindow:self.window
                        event:eventToEdit
              completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode, 
  GTLRCalendar_Event *event) {
              // Callback
              if (returnCode == NSModalResponseOK) {
                [self editSelectedEventWithEvent:event];
              }
            }];
     }
  }
```

Comment: hiii could u help me how to integrate google calendar in swift @Dipak Dhondge

Comment: Yes,I can help you with swift google calendar integration.

Comment: how to connect and create event from my app

Comment: I have code in Objective C only.Recently I have integrated with My project.Sorry dude I don't have code for swift.But I am going to share some useful url for calendar.Please have a look
1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801031/adding-a-google-calendar-event-in-swift
2.https://github.com/theandrewdavis/ios-google-calendar
3.I referred google library for adding, creating & deleting events
:-https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest

Comment: bro could u share me steps how u integrated with objective c

Comment: Hello Dilip, I followed the steps given in the following URL:- 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios
Follow above URL steps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to post or insert some event in google calendar, well you can do this using following :

Use https POST request, and make a NSURLSession request, using url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

after events, add your data.

Comment: i want to insert the events on perticular time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [insert an event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) in a specific time, then your request should look like this.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
"end": {
"dateTime": "2016-10-08T8:00:00",
"timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2016-10-08T6:00:00",
"timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
}
}
```

You need to specify the [`start.dateTime`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#start.dateTime) and the [`end.dateTime`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#end.dateTime) in your request.

Include also the `timeZone` that you want to use. This API needs an IANA Time Zone Format that you can see in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: can we convert general timezone format (eg.`IST`) to IANA format(eg.`Asia/Kolkatta`)

Comment: The Asia/Kolkatta is available in the IANA format, can you clarify your question?

Comment: I've a timezone which returns the timezone string as `IST`, is it possible to convert `IST` to IANA format like `Asia/Kolkatta`?

Comment: But calendar API only accepts an IANA format. Try to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014341/how-to-convert-time-correctly-across-timezones) if it can help you.

Comment: hiii could u help me how to integrate google calendar in swift  @KENdi