# google calender API converting timed event to all day events in JS

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I used the sample for google calendar in google API website using JS. everything is perfect. the only problem is the events on my calendar are timed and they disappear after the end time. I want to convert this events to all day events so they stay all day in my website where I display the events. I tried to google this problem but there is no answer. changing the events in google calendar it self is not an option, everything has to be done in the background.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: First of all go through the API documentation of the google calendar. If you find any event subscription method then you can write a logic in the particular scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all the events in my calendar still exist even though they are already finished. I suggest you to create a calendar event using the [`Events: insert`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) of the Calendar API and check if the created events here are staying in your calendar (because mine are all stayed in my calendar)

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829301/want-to-add-event-in-google-calender) on how I create/insert an event in the calendar.

Also, check the example [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) on how to create events in the calendar using javascript.