# Adding a google calendar event in swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a Google Calendar event using the API in Swift. I am kind of lost at the moment in how to go about that. More specifically creating a `GTLRCalendar_Event` object to pass through `GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert.query()`. Any way to go about this?

I've written the following code

```
var newEvent: GTLRCalendar_Event = GTLRCalendar_Event()
        newEvent.summary = name

        //set GTLRDateTimes
        var startTime: GTLRDateTime = GTLRDateTime(date:startTimeObject!, offsetMinutes: offsetMinutes)
        var endTime: GTLRDateTime = GTLRDateTime(date:endTimeObject!, offsetMinutes: offsetMinutes)

        newEvent.reminders?.useDefault = 0

        newEvent.start?.dateTime = startTime
        newEvent.end?.dateTime = endTime

        let service: GTLRCalendarService = GTLRCalendarService()
        let query:GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert.query(withObject: newEvent, calendarId:"primary")
        service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(_ callbackTicket: GTLRServiceTicket, _ event: GTLRCalendar_Event, _ callbackError: Error?) -> Void in
            print("executed query")
            if callbackError == nil {
                print("added")
                print(newEvent.summary);
            }
            else {
                print("add failed")
                print(callbackError)
            }
            } as? GTLRServiceCompletionHandler)
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written and describe where you're getting an error.

Comment: Apologies for the super late response. I've included my code

Comment: It doesn't return any errors. Just doesn't work. I have been using the example code provided on Google's github page for the API in Objective-C but I've had trouble converting it into swift [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/763e1de99004b3117983f12ac3d889ed2e697630/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m#L512-L583)

Comment: @RickRaf have u implemented google calendar i need help from u

Comment: @RickRaf have u successfully implemented google calendar i need one help

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work in Swift 4. I based it on the Java code example that Google has because that one was the most similar. I hope this answers all of your questions. I am sure there is a prettier way to do this, but I don't know it. :)

```
//Declares the new event
var newEvent: GTLRCalendar_Event = GTLRCalendar_Event()

//this is setting the parameters of the new event
newEvent.summary = ("Google I/O 2015")
newEvent.location = ("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")

//I ran into some problems with the date formatting and this is what I ended with. 

//Start Date. The offset adds time to the current time so if you run the         program at 12:00 then it will record a time of 12:05 because of the 5 minute offset 

let startDateTime: GTLRDateTime = GTLRDateTime(date: Date(), offsetMinutes: 5)
let startEventDateTime: GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime = GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime()
startEventDateTime.dateTime = startDateTime
newEvent.start = startEventDateTime
print(newEvent.start!)

//Same as start date, but for the end date
let endDateTime: GTLRDateTime = GTLRDateTime(date: Date(), offsetMinutes: 50)
let endEventDateTime: GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime = GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime()
endEventDateTime.dateTime = endDateTime
newEvent.end = endEventDateTime
print(newEvent.end!)


let service: GTLRCalendarService = GTLRCalendarService()

//The query 
let query =
GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert.query(withObject: newEvent, calendarId:"Past your calendar ID here this is specific to the calendar you want to edit and can be found under the google calendar settings")

//This is the part that I forgot. Specify your fields! I think this will change when you add other perimeters, but I need to review how this works more. 
query.fields = "id";

//This is actually running the query you just built
self.service.executeQuery(
       query,
       completionHandler: {(_ callbackTicket:GTLRServiceTicket, 
                            _  event:GTLRCalendar_Event,
                            _ callbackError: Error?) -> Void in} 
                           as? GTLRServiceCompletionHandler
           )
      }
```

Comment: could u help me in google calendar implementation swift

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem during the lack of resources at this topic, those are the steps

->configure your app with google calendar account

1-go to https://console.developers.google.com/  add a new project with app bundle id and name

2- go to dashboard click Enable APIS AND SERVICES then choose a calendar API Service and enable It.

3-choose credentials from the side menu and click CREATE CREDENTIALS Link from top of the page and add OAuth Client ID

4-open firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/

5- click add project and choose your existing app  and continue

6- follow the steps here https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup until download "GoogleService-Info.plist" and add it to your app 
-> write code to add an event to google calendar

1-follow those steps to add google sign-in 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift

2-
      // Create an event to the Google Calendar's user

```
func addEventoToGoogleCalendar(summary : String, description :String, startTime : String, endTime : String) {
    let calendarEvent = GTLRCalendar_Event()

    calendarEvent.summary = "\(summary)"
    calendarEvent.descriptionProperty = "\(description)"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startTime)
    let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: endTime)

    guard let toBuildDateStart = startDate else {
        print("Error getting start date")
        return
    }
    guard let toBuildDateEnd = endDate else {
        print("Error getting end date")
        return
    }
    calendarEvent.start = buildDate(date: toBuildDateStart)
    calendarEvent.end = buildDate(date: toBuildDateEnd)

    let insertQuery = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsInsert.query(withObject: calendarEvent, calendarId: "primary")

    service.executeQuery(insertQuery) { (ticket, object, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Event inserted")
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

// Helper to build date
func buildDate(date: Date) -> GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime {
    let datetime = GTLRDateTime(date: date)
    let dateObject = GTLRCalendar_EventDateTime()
    dateObject.dateTime = datetime
    return dateObject
}
// Helper for showing an alert
func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert
    )
    let ok = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
        handler: nil
    )
    alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

here is the GitHub link  https://github.com/emanShedeed/writeEventToGoogleCalendar